# Is there a way to use bootstrap with jquery 3.x

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, obsolete

I had Bootstrap 3.3.6 and jQuery 1.12.4 working in my website.

As jQuery 3.0.0 was released into production, I upgraded jQuery to jQuery-3.0.0.js. After that, when I ran my site I got this console error.

> Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3

Tried adding [jQuery Migrate 3.0.0](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.js) plugin, but it didn't work too.

The error still persists and *Bootstrap's JavaScript* won't work. Is there a work around? Or do one have to wait till the next release of bootstrap?

Found this in Bootstrap source.

```
+function ($) {
  'use strict';
  var version = $.fn.jquery.split(' ')[0].split('.')
  if ((version[0] < 2 && version[1] < 9) || (version[0] == 1 && version[1] == 9 && version[2] < 1) || (version[0] > 2)) {
    throw new Error('Bootstrap\'s JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3')
  }
}(jQuery);
```

Does this mean that one have to wait for a later version?

Comment: `Does this mean that one have to wait for a later version?` For the moment, yes. I believe that bootstrap has issues with the 3.0 version of jQuery, hence the block. They are working on this. You could amend the bootstrap source to remove the block, but I would not recommend it at all

Comment: Here is the corresponding issue on github [Bootstrap v3 is not compatible with jQuery 3.0](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16834)

Comment: thanks guys. I see it as a open issue in [v3.3.7 Milestone](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/milestone/34)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bootstrap 3.3.7 now supports jQuery 3+.

Comment: Does not appear to work with jquery 3.5.1 - it is failing in the `getParent()` function.

Comment: I realise is this an old post, but just in case someone else is wrestling with this issue.  I can confirm there are issues with Boostrap 3.3.7 and jQuery 3.6.0.   For me, it's throwing an error within the bootstrap.min.js file (JQMIGRATE: jQuery.isFunction() is deprecated).  I'll post a workaround if I can come up with one.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following to the top of the *bootstrap.min.js* file and tweaking the isFunction condition worked for me.

```
function isFunction(func){
    return typeof func === "function";
}
```

And then, still in *bootstrap.min.js*, find:

```
a.isFunction
```

and replace with:

```
isFunction
```